# Can't remove legend in scatterplot

Tags: r

Here is my code

```
scatterplot(LitterMass~WormMass | Site,  reg.line=FALSE, smooth=FALSE, 
              spread=FALSE, id.method='mahal', id.n = 2, boxplots=FALSE, 
              span=0.5, by.groups=FALSE, data=wormdata,
              col=c("black","gray78","gray68","gray58","gray48"))
```

I am trying to move the legend from it's default location, but the 
legend("topright") 
does not seem to be working, what else can I try?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't like to add legend to your plot, simply use

```
legend.plot = FALSE
```

In general, developers use legend for their plots as a second step. Most of the times, After you draw your plot on the window, then only you can decide, where to keep the legend for your graph for better visibility.

Refer [legend](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/legend.html)! page for more details and examples of its usage.

Answer (score 0):

maybe...

```
scatterplot(LitterMass~WormMass | Site,  reg.line=FALSE, smooth=FALSE, 
              spread=FALSE, id.method='mahal', id.n = 2, boxplots=FALSE, 
              span=0.5, by.groups=FALSE, data=wormdata,
              col=c("black","gray78","gray68","gray58","gray48"),
              legend.plot = FALSE)
# the important addition here is legend.plot = FALSE)


library(car)
scatterplot(prestige ~ income|type, data=Prestige, legend.coords="topleft")
# this plots with legend topleft
scatterplot(prestige ~ income|type, data=Prestige, legend.coords="topright")
# this plots with legend topright
scatterplot(prestige ~ income|type, data=Prestige, legend.plot=FALSE)
# this removes the legend
```